# Rotation, move objects are not working in OS X 10.10

Tags: shortcut, osx

I started working on blender in mac OS X 10.10, none of keyboard keys like G for move , R for rotation are not working as the way expected. I have added emulate 3key mouse also but didn't get any response from blender screen.

How to troubleshoot  keyboard shortcuts, mouse settings work for blender in mac 
OS X ?

Comment: are other shortcuts working fine ? are you using the default "Blender " keys layout

Comment: have you tried setting keys configuration to default, or possibly deleting blender and installing it again?

Comment: I am using default blender keys layout only, but shortcuts not working in blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled Emulate 3 mouse button its working fine now.

Hold MMB for rotate

Hold Shift+MMB for pan

Mouse scroll up/down for zoom

Right click to select object

Left click to complete the selection and process.

ESC key or press again to undo the changes happen in the selection process.